# android sqlite save image in database or path

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

i am making an android chat application that shows list of friends with image from mysql database..... i want to also store it locally i just want to know if i show store the images in the sqlite database or on the sdcard and save the path in the sqlite database .... I know saving the path is better but the thing is the user can delete the folder or some images int the folder which i dont want any advice.

and this is the code i found that should work

```
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet("your image url");
HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
    if ( entity != null) {
      // insert to database
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
      getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cache folder and user can't delete this  folder
if image an avatar, you can use picasso + okhttp (picasso  uses the okhttp  for disk caching )

Comment: how do i store in cache

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getCacheDir%28%29